# What is the time complexity of Arrays.parallelSetAll()?

Tags: java, java-8

I just read from : [Everything about java 8](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/)
that, java 8 adds Arrays.parallelSetAll()

```
int[] array = new int[8];
AtomicInteger i= new AtomicInteger();
Arrays.parallelSetAll(array, operand -> i.incrementAndGet());
```

[Edited] Is it O(1) or a constant time complexity on the same machine for same no.of elements in array ? What sort of performance improvement is indicated by the method name?

Comment: How can it be O(1)? You don't have an infinite number of CPU cores.

Comment: As a side note, I suppose you understand that the array will probably ***not*** contain the numbers in ascending order. If you do want them in ascending order, you should use: `int[] array = new int[8]; Arrays.parallelSetAll(array, i -> i);`.

Comment: You cannot increment an `AtomicInteger` in parallel. Hence you can expect an operation consisting of that increment only to be even *slower* when executing with multiple threads. Beside that you don’t seem to have understood the `O(…)` complexity notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start off, it can never be O(1), more clarification following:

I am using that `n = array.length`, which in your case is `8`, however that does not matter as it could also be a very big number.

Now observe that normally you would do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = i.incrementAndGet();
}
```

This is with Java 8 much easier:

```
Arrays.setAll(array, v -> i.incrementAndGet());
```

Observe that they both take O(n) time.

Now take into account that you execute the code parallel, but there are no guarantees as to *how* it executes it, you do not know the number of parallellizations it does under the hood, if any at all for such a low number.

Therefore it still takes O(n) time, because you cannot prove that it will parallellize over n threads.

**Edit**, as an extra, I have observed that you seem to think that parallellizing an action means that any O(k) will converge to O(1), where `k = n` or `k = n^2`, etc.
This is not the case in practice as you can prove that you never have `k` processor cores available.

An intuitive argument is your own computer, if you are lucky it may have 8 cores, therefore the maximum time you could get under perfect parallellization conditions is O(n / 8).
*I can already hear the people from the future laughing at that we only had 8 CPU cores...*

Comment: Good explanation. The "future-comment" made my day :-)

Comment: In fact, the theory behind the O-notation is not really sufficient any more for a world where parallel computers are omnipresent, and considering the fact that the number of cores will double every 2 years in the future. There may be workarounds like saying "It runs in O(n²/m) for `n` input elements on `m` cores", but as far as I know, there is no really profound theory behind that. (E.g. one would have to include Amdahl/Gustafson somwhere in such a theory)

Comment: @Marco13 - If we make the simplifying assumption that the number of cores on a computer is bounded, and the problem has a scaling parameter that is not bounded, then the math behind Big-O notation works for multi-core computers too.

Comment: @StephenC One could argue that this is just a theoretical construct, and this theory per se is not related to hardware. But in the same way as the *asymptotic* nature of the O-notation and its "infinite input size" are unrelated to reality, the implied assumption that all programs run on a single core is no longer realistic. One should at least consider whether the difference between a perfectly parallelizable O(nlogn) algorithm or an inherently sequential O(n) algorithm may be important, or whether the number of cores should somehow be included in this theory. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @Marco13 - *"... and this theory per se is not related to hardware"*.  This is practical, not theoretical.  I have yet to encounter a computer system where the number of processors is *unbounded*.  (I think that the laws of physics might have something to say about that ...)  Like I said, the assumption is that the application runs on a computer with a BOUNDED number of cores ... even if the bound *could* be "rather large".

Comment: @StephenC Yet *in theory* you could build a system that would order new processor cores whenever it runs out of cores, and well *in theory* there is an unlimited amount of resources, so this should be possible.

Comment: @skiwi - The laws of physics contradict your assumptions.  (A computation theory that *depends* on violating the laws of physics / the universe ... as we understand them ... is not relevant to the real world, and real world computing.)

Comment: @StephenC: Sure, the number of cores is bounded. But the number of elements that you can throw into a sorting function is also bounded *in practice* (!). Still, I'm not aware of a commonly used basis for a differentiation between serial sorting algorithms and things like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter . This does not mean that no such theory exists (I'm not an expert here) but *if* it exists, it's by far not as well-known as the classical O-notation. I just think that *if* it exists, it should be tought in Universities - and if it does *not* exist, it should be developed ;-)

Comment: @Marco13 - If you want to, you can include P as a parameter in the big O notation; e.g. `parallelSetAll` *could* be `O(N/P)`.  The problem is that 1) the math is tricky (limits with N independent variables), 2) the analysis of the code is generally harder for parallel algorithms, and 3) hardware rarely behaves like the theoretical analysis says it should, due to various contention issues.

Comment: @Marco13 - The trouble with teaching this kind of thing at University is that the student needs to understand two difficult topics: i.e regular complexity analysis, and parallel algorithmics.  And there is only so much advanced stuff you can fit into an undergraduate curriculum, and still have time to cover the basic stuff that gets people jobs.  Still, as computing changes, curricula will change.

Comment: @StephenC That's exactly what I said in my first comment. And I think that something like the concepts of "work and depth" from Guy Blelloch ( http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/cacm/node1.html ) should become more mainstream nowadays.

Comment: @StephenC (regarding second comment) This is true, the time for the topics that "should" be considered as the basics is rather limited. But parallel programming is IMHO such a significant game-changer that it should be emphasized more.

Comment: @Marco13 - Actually, what you said at the start was that big-O notation is not sufficient.  It is sufficient if you use it appropriately.  And if you make the simplifying assumption, you don't even need to incorporate `P` into the notation to get useful results about scalability.

Comment: @StephenC Here comes the warning "~avoid discussion" ... we will hardly come to a final conclusion here regarding all aspects. Of course, O-notation should not be abandoned ;-) I was just wondering why the parallelization commonly does not seem to be taken into account for such an analysis (and wondered how it *could* be taken into account)

Comment: @Marco13: simply said, the big O notation only tells you the *complexity* of an algorithm but ignores any kind of optimization that will not change the complexity. And executing in parallel is such an optimization. As a consequence `O(…)` only tells you how the algorithm *scales* with *`n`* getting bigger, however, a real computer will have a practical limit for the problem size it can handle, so when reaching that point you won’t scale up anyway. If you can optimize your code to handle the practical maximum “fast enough” you don’t need to care about the complexity. But beware underestimation.

Answer (score 5):

It is `O(N)`.  Calling `Arrays.parallelSetAll(...)` involves assignments to set a total of `array.length` array elements.  Even if those assignments are spread across `P` processors, the total number of assignments is *linearly proportional* to the length of the array.  Take `N` as the length of the array, and math is obvious.

The thing to realize is that `P` ... the number of available processors ... is going to be a constant for any given execution of a program on a single computer.  (Or if it is not a constant, there will be a constant upper bound.)  And a computation whose sole purpose is to assign values to an array only makes sense when executed on a single computer.